# SQL search with like, and cut result by spaces

Tags: mysql

Let's presume I have the following table:

> ID      City
>   1        New York
>   2        London
>   3        Yorkshire
>   4        West Yorkshire
>   5        North Yorkshire
>   6        Downyork

How could I fetch every row from this table (id 1,3,4,5) which has a word in it, that starts with York?

> We can safely assume that each and every word is separated by a single space

If I do

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE City LIKE '%York%'
```

the row with id 6 is also returned.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Would you only want 'Yorkshire' to be returned?

Comment: Of course line 6 also matches. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: No, I would like to get every row, where the City field has a word, which **starts with** York, so rows with id 1,3,4,5

Comment: Yes, but that is not what you coded.See the answer below, it explains...

Comment: He means 6 (`Downyork`) in the last line.

Comment: Yes, corrected it, sorry, it was a typo

Comment: Nevertheless, `%york%` _will_ match `Downyork`.

Comment: I know it matches, that is my problem, I want a query which won't return a match for the 6th row:)

Comment: @arkascha Engage brain

Comment: Then code what you want to retrieve. You cannot expect that somehow magically sql knows you want a space there. That is not what you asked it. The `%` matches everything, with or without space. What do you expect? If you want to match york with either a space in front or nothing (string start), than you have to ask that. Just as shown in the answers below.

Comment: @Strawberry I have the impression I am the only one here who does...

Comment: @arkascha Does the phrase 'downyork' have a word within it that starts with the string 'york'?

Comment: @Strawberry No it does not. But that does not matter. It matches the pattern `%york%`. The `LIKE` operator knows nothing about the concept of a "word". The pattern used in the query does not mention the concept "word". So why should that be applicable here? As said before: you expect magic.

Comment: @arkascha Perhaps the OP doesn't know the solution, which is perhaps why they asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE City LIKE '% York%' OR City LIKE 'York%'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this slow down the query very much? Having two LIKE's in it. The table on which I would like to use a simmilar query, has a much more data, then the demo I've posted in the question. Isn't there a built in mysql function that does this?

Comment: No, your query is already an expensive table scan on `City` because of the leading `%` in the like query. Adding an extra condition to that will not have measurable impact. The simple alternatives are splitting each line on spaces and doing group scans (MUCH slower) or regexps (INCREDIBLY MUCH SLOWER). Once you have a table scan you're kinda screwed anyway, but at least it's linear slowness.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai now see regular expressions.

Comment: As said regexps (short for 'regular expressions') will sort of instakill your server if this query is run frequently on tons of data. While impossible to estimate exactly without more knowledge about servers and usecase it's pretty safe to assume it will be 10 to 100 times slower than straight partial string matching with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that every word is separated by a single space, then you can split your query to find fields which start with York and fields which contain " York". This would find everything except London and Downyork.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE City LIKE '% York%' OR City LIKE 'York%'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this slow down the query very much? Having two LIKE's in it. The table on which I would like to use a simmilar query, has a much more data, then the demo I've posted in the question. Isn't there a built in mysql function that does this?